# Which colors do I need to change to fix this unreadable text in KDE?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, plasma5

So I have applied a Kvantum theme called Akava with its own colors in KDE along with the WhiteSurDark theme for the KDE Widgets. The problem is that following type of text seems quite hard to read in the widgets and the application menus. How do I change the color for the description text in KDE Panel Widgets and for the highlight background of application context menus?

[image: Unreadable description text in KDE Widgets]              [image: Hard to read context menus]